react-native-geolocation-service/react_native_geolocation_service.modulemap' not found
I'm getting the error below when I try to run a build for my react native app. I followed the right steps to install react-native-geolocation-service.
React native version: 0.75.2
I'm building using an M1 chip. How do i fix the error below?
Error:
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/jonahgeek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JustKnow-cqtcemamhokfsdbnzoqovxeppjhm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/react-native-geolocation-service/react_native_geolocation_service.modulemap' not found
Command SwiftGeneratePch emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

